# Memory management of Service Oriented Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, architecture

I am developing an iOS app with Service Oriented Architecture approach.
Each modul of the architecture will communicate to each other via protocols.

There is a central(start point) class, which initializes modules. That class keeps strong reference of the modules.

```
 Central->  Module A            
        ->  Module B  
        ->  Module C  
        ->   …

  ModuleA -> id<ModuleC protocol> delegate // this is a just call back
          -> id<ModuleB protocol> reference // to use services of ModuleB

  ModuleB-> id<ModuleA protocol> reference // to use services of ModuleA
         -> id<ModuleC protocol> reference // to use services of ModuleC
       ..............
```

Apple docs [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447) that a “parent” object should maintain strong reference to it’s children and that the children should have weak reference to their parents.
I put delegate to weak. But in case ModuleA and ModuleB, which have references to each other, is not clear for me and that is the question.

Edit:

And how to proceed if there is no Central class which holds the strong references?

Comment: I'd use weak references, since they are already strong-referenced by Central

Comment: Same as sonxurso, if you use strong references ModuleA and ModuleB will never be released as each one will keep a reference to the other one.

Comment: I agree. please see the question, I edited it- if there is no Central class.

Comment: maybe make sense to vote the question to pay attention other users? Because this is very important and I guess you are interested as well.